# Running mongod as a windows service

Tags: windows, windows-services, mongodb

i have installed mongodb on  win32 and i am trying to run it as a service.

I have followed the instructions posted here: http://www.deltasdevelopers.com/post/Running-MongoDB-as-a-Windows-Service.aspx

but when when windows tries to 'load'/'run' the service there is a problem. I see the service under the services control banner constantly in the 'starting' state.

The result: the service is not started and windows is constantly trying to start it without success.

The instructions i have followed are:

At the command line

C:\mongodb\mongod -install
then
C:\mongodb\mongod -service

Then i modified the Win Registry Entry for the MongoDB Service by setting the ImagePath key to the value of C:\mongodb\mongodb.exe -service

Any advice? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: sorry people solved it...
Windows Registry should also include the --dbpath flag so the correct value is C:\mongodb\mongod.exe --dbpath C:\data\db --service

Comment: http://www.webiyo.com/2011/02/install-mongodb-service-on-windows-7.html#more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for future reference: [running mongo as a windows service](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Windows+Service)

Also lots of people seem to be saying: specify the whole path to the mongod.exe:

```
c:\mongo\mongod.exe --logpath "c:\mongo\logs\mongo.log" --logappend --dbpath "c:\mongo\data" --directoryperdb --install
```

Also if you're running Windows 7 don't forget to run the command window as an administrator.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it this way just cause I like to customize/organize things better:
Unzip mongo to where you want.

I like putting all the configuration in a file (my preference, since I didnt like default location of C:/data/db, and didn't like all the options as commandline params)...
Looks something like: 
[C:\dev\mongodb\data\mongodb.conf]

```
dbpath = C:\dev\mongodb\data\db
logpath = C:\dev\mongodb\data\mongodb.log.txt
logappend = false
```

Then I put C:\dev\mongodb\bin in my Env Variable's PATH (so can call mongo.exe from any dir), but not needed...

Then on command line to install the Windows Service:

```
$ cd C:\dev\mongodb\bin
$ mongod.exe -f C:\dev\mongodb\data\mongodb.conf --install
```

It will create a Windows Service which if you want, can start manually via:

```
$ net start MongoDB
```

//Use qoutes if changed service name (via -serviceName to mongod --install), like: net start "Mongo DB"

Answer (score 1):

Specifying several parameters at once is a good choice.
mongod 
--install
to install as a service

--rest 
to enable rest access to mongodb

–master 
to set up mongodb instance as master.

–logpath 
this is mandatory when you install mongodb as service

--dbpath
this too is mandatory for mongodb to run.

[Here is a step by step guide](http://www.webiyo.com/2011/02/install-mongodb-service-on-windows-7.html) describing the installation of MongoDB Service on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I have been faced similar issue.  And i tried above solutions still have not get any result.

finally below code is solved my issue.

-> Command prompt open as administrator.

-> Copy and paste the below code after changing the proper bin and config path.

```
sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "\"d:\MongoDB\bin\mongod.exe\" --service --config=\"d:\MongoDB\mongo.cfg\"" DisplayName= "MongoDB" start= "auto"
```

Happy Coding !!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether you're running as a service or not, you need to specify the --dbpath argument to mongod.exe.

Also, you shouldn't have to edit the registry. You can just issue the command like this:

C:\mongodb\mongod.exe --dbpath C:\data\db --install