# How to enable --rest in Windows XP 32 bit

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have successfully installed Mongo DB as a Window Service and verified service in my msconfig. It is version 2.0.6 which is compatible of my windows xp 32bit. And I just wanted to use the Simple REST Interface through my browser like localhost:28017/databaseName/collectionName/

I stored some data successfully via NODE.JS and I know I can retrieve the data through command line. But I just really want to view it REST Interface through my browser.

Since the browser shows "REST is not enabled.  use --rest to turn on. check that port 28017 is secured for the network too." I think I suppose to enable the --rest on the command line but I don't know how and where to enter it.

Comment: this has already been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741039/running-mongod-as-a-windows-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If MongoDB was installed with a [`--config` file](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/), you can [enable `rest` there](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#rest):

```
rest=true
```

Otherwise, you'll have to re-install MongoDB with a `--config` file or with `--rest` enabled after stopping and deleting the existing MongoDB service:

```
mongod.exe --install --rest ...
```

Or, through `regedit`, you can [edit the service's `ImagePath`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7190480).

Comment: how to activate this using Ubuntu machine